# Poems/Phrases: Life is meaningful

Tags: word-requests

Looking for any sort of story/fable, poem/epic, phrase/chengyu that expresses that life is meaningful.

It can be

- the hope that life is meaningful
- the conviction that life is actually meaningful
- the desire that life will become meaningful
- or any variation

Just hoping that it will be something that **most people will be familiar with**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more modern poem, perhaps you might be interested in 面朝大海春暖花开.

P.S. There's quite of bit of irony here as 海子 committed suicide shortly after writing this poem.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:
天生我材必有用，千金散尽还复来。

Answer (score 3):

日出东海落西山，愁也一天，喜也一天
长风破浪会有时,直挂云帆济沧海